# Loading huge from json to listview causes app not to respond when scrolling. xamarin.android

Tags: c#, json, listview, http, xamarin.android

I'm loading a huge data from json(with images) to my list view and it causes my app not to respond when scrolling but if i press wait on my emulator.. I can scroll it but it made my application very lag.. however. I have a detailactivity in my application which is also from my json. after clicking 1 item in my listview and proceeding to my detail activity, lag goes away.any work around for this? I put the link of my json file below. I think my scroll view is making a hard time loading my images.. as ive done my research it says that i should memorycache while converting my image to bytes.. but how? :O

heres how I convert my images to bytes..

```
public class ImageHelper
{
    public static Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
    {
        Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Others");
            var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
            if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            }
        }
        return imageBitmap;
    }        
}
```

[My json file.](https://ia601507.us.archive.org/10/items/mountainsData/mountainsData.json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Piccaso  https://components.xamarin.com/view/square.picasso for asynchronous image download and cache. Its works pretty well.

Comment: @merbsanda glad to know that. You may want to mark one of the answers as accepted if it helped you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) handle it for you. It's an awesome well-known library for image caching and compression.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few tips

- Reduce the size of image or compress it
- Do pagination i.e load data in chunks and load more as the user scrolls down
- Open profiler to note at what point memory cross danger sign